# ignore first linet on import csv

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ignore the first line on csv import file.

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r"); //Membuka file dan membacanya
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT into t_dil_lpb  (id_pelanggan,nama_pelanggan,gardu,tiang,lat,lon,tarif_daya,no_met,alamat,no_tlp,th_buat,kwh,segel,tegangan,arus,daya,total,sisa,idx,merek,mcb,display,ada,performansi,kode_pesan,waktu_ambil,keterangan,area,rayon)
                values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]','$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]','$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]','$data[23]','$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]','$area','$rayon')"; //data array sesuaikan dengan jumlah kolom pada CSV anda mulai dari “0” bukan “1”
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: have you tried continue...

Comment: just add counter starting with 0 before while loop and put increment counter and then put condition if counter == 1 then continue

Answer (score 0):

Before while loop you can use fgetcsv function.

```
$firstLine = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
...
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$row = -1;

 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    ++$row;
    if($row == 0 ) continue; 
    ...
```

We start at `-1` that way we can increment the row count before anything.

Another way is to create a header array:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = array_combine($headers, $data);
    ..
```

Then you an use the headers to reference the data, but `array_combine` requires both arrays are the same length so if you have missing delimiters it can cause a lot of trouble.

So if your first 2 rows are

```
 first,middle,last
 John,J,Doe
```

Then the above code (with array_combine) will give you

```
[
   'first' => John,
   'middle' => J,
   'last' => Doe
]
```

If you used the SpLFileObject Class you could do `$obj->seek(1);`

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

Personally I prefer the second example, with the SplFileObject class, but I hate procedural code...